# Should we have tags for nomenclature + taxonomy or only taxonomy?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

There is an earlier tag synonym suggestion for taxonomy <- nomenclature. However, I see [nomenclature](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nomenclature) as a more general term, for dealing with all sorts of naming/classification issues, while taxonomy is only dealing with the naming of species and other taxa. I have suggested a wiki edit to clarify this: https://biology.stackexchange.com/tags/nomenclature/info.

What are your opinions? Should we use both [nomenclature](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nomenclature) and [taxonomy](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/taxonomy) or only [taxonomy](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/taxonomy).

Answer (score 2):

I think at present they are being used very differently and most of the [nomenclature](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nomenclature) tagged questions could not have a [taxonomy](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/taxonomy) tag added.  I'd favour keeping them separate.